# Open apps ubuntu

Tags: search

I used Ubuntu in a day now and I have a question. How do you open apps through writing in the upper left corner? I watched a YouTuber open an app, the thing that I saw was a text in the upper left corner and then did the app open. How do you do that?

[image]

Comment: Would you prefer to use the same method over the built-in method of pressing [Super] (sometimes called “The Windows key”) and typing the application? 

Comment: We have no idea what OS & particularly release you're talking about.  Given Ubuntu is also available as many *flavors* there are multiple desktop choices available (each working slightly different), so in order to be helpful you need to be specific as to what software stack you're asking about (start with what release of Ubuntu?)

Answer (score 1):

That looks like [`dmenu`](https://tools.suckless.org/dmenu/), a lightweight program for presenting a menu of options. When you install it (`sudo apt install suckless-tools`) and run `dmenu_run` from the terminal it shows a list of installed programs you can choose from. Typically people add a key binding for `dmenu_run` in whatever desktop environment they're using.